# Can I use more than one name attribute in HTML tag?

Tags: html, django, forms, django-templates

I am doing a django project.

But I wanted to have radio buttons grouped as well as name of the buttons to work with django.

Is it okay to use two name attributes in one HTML tag?

Will I be facing any errors if I do so?

Below is my code I am stuck in.

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" name="removePunc"> Remove Punctuations
    <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input `name` attributes must be unique to send data using traditional forms. If you find yourself needing more attributes, use the `data-` attributes. Pls share some code to undertand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to label the group of radio buttons add `class="group1"` to all of the radio buttons instead of `name="group1"`.

```
<label for="removePunc">Remove Punctuations</label>
<input type="radio" class="group1" name="removePunc">

<label for="button2">Button 2</label>
<input type="radio" class="group1" name="button2">

<label for="button3">Button 3</label>
<input type="radio" class="group1" name="button3">
```